# Using each item in a list box

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a new application and am trying to work with a Listbox. What I am trying to do is run a task with each item in the Listbox one at a time.

**Example:**

Items in Listbox:

- Dog
- Cat
- Fish
- Cow

For this example, I would like the program to start at the top at 'Dog', display the result, then go to 'Cat', and so on until there are no more items.

Side note: I would also like it if there was a way to highlight what item it was currently on.

Thanks in advance guys, I am working on learning some of the other features of the ListBox with this new application.

Comment: It is unclear what you expect to be the result when the Item is 'Dog'. Do you simply whish to display the item text?

Comment: @Steve Correct, display the item text

Comment: Is this a Winforms application?

Comment: @Steve Yes, sorry for not including that

Comment: looping over string items of a listbox _foreach(string s in listbox1.Items) MessageBox.Show(s);_

Answer (score 1):

The `ListBox` has some properties you may be interested in.

- You want to highlight the item. Therefore, you'll need the `SelectedIndex`
- Since you want to select it, a standard `For` loop will be needed.
- To access the items in the list, you use the `Items` collection.
- The `Items` collection has a `Count` property.

Here is an example based on what you provided. `AnimalList` is a ListBox, and `ShowNames` is a Button:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      AnimalList.Items.AddRange({"Dog", "Cat", "Fish", "Cow"})

   End Sub

   Private Sub ShowNames_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowNames.Click

      For i As Integer = 0 To AnimalList.Items.Count - 1

         AnimalList.SelectedIndex = i
         MessageBox.Show(AnimalList.Items(i).ToString())

      Next

   End Sub
```

If you set the `SelectedIndex`, you can also access the `SelectedItem` property.

When you have a multi-select list, there are also `SelectedIndices` and `SelectedItems` properties.